# Execute command after view is loaded WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, triggers, command

I have a project based WPF and MVVM.
My project is based on a wizard containing a content control which shows my views (User Controls)
I want to execute a command after the view is loaded completely, I would like the user to see the view UI immediately after the command will be executed.

I tried using :

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartProgressCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But the command is executed before I see the view UI and it's not what I'm looking for.

Does anyone have an idea how should I need to implement it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because even though technically the view is loaded (i.e: all the components are ready in memory), your app is not idle yet, and thus the UI isn't refreshed yet.

Setting a command using interaction triggers on the `Loaded` event is already good, as there is no better event to attach to.
Now to really wait until the UI is shown, do this in your `StartProgress()` (I'm assuming here that this is the name of the method that `StartProgressCommand` point to):

```
public void StartProgress()
{
    new DispatcherTimer(//It will not wait after the application is idle.
                       TimeSpan.Zero,
                       //It will wait until the application is idle
                       DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, 
                       //It will call this when the app is idle
                       dispatcherTimer_Tick, 
                       //On the UI thread
                       Application.Current.Dispatcher); 
}

private static void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Now the UI is really shown, do your computations
}
```

Comment: Old I know but for those in a hurry here is how to end the thread:

In your event handler

var timer = sender as DispatcherTimer;
timer.Stop();

Comment: I dont really know, if this is a very good approach, but it works in did!

Answer (score 18):

You could use the Dispatcher for this and set the priority to ApplicationIdle so that it will on execute when everything has finished

```
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
            new Action(() =>
            {
               StartProgressCommand.Invoke(args);

            }));
```

more information on the dispatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx

cheers.
ste.

Comment: This seems like a much cleaner solutions than the accepted answer. Why start a timer when you're only going to run one cycle?

Comment: `Invoke` didn't seem to do the trick for me, so I've used `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`. that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

another way to do it:

define this `xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"` and `xmlns:mi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"` on your usercontrol XAML and add Microsoft.Expression.Interactions assembly on your project. use CallMethodAction on your trigger, just as bellow:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <mi:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="StartProgressCommand"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Put the triger inside the root element of your usercontrol, e.g: grid. And change your StartProgressCommand, in your ViewModel class, from command to plain old regular Method, e.g:

```
public void StartProgressCommand()
{
  /* put your program logic here*/
}
```

It'll run the method exactly one time every time your user control rendered.

Comment: Easy and precise... just edited with `xmlns:i` that was missing

Comment: this doesn't work for me it's telling me that the method or operation is not implemented

Comment: The loaded event is called every time the View is rendered. This can result in problems, when there are views added to this parent view.

Answer (score 1):

We use a the timer solution - i too was very dubious about this but it does seem to work fine.

```
public static class DispatcherExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, DispatcherTimer> timers =
        new Dictionary<string, DispatcherTimer>();
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    public static void DelayInvoke(this Dispatcher dispatcher, string namedInvocation,
        Action action, TimeSpan delay,
        DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            RemoveTimer(namedInvocation);
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer(delay, priority, (s, e) =>
                {
                    RemoveTimer(namedInvocation);
                    action();
                }, dispatcher);
            timer.Start();
            timers.Add(namedInvocation, timer);
        }
    }


    public static void CancelNamedInvocation(this Dispatcher dispatcher, string namedInvocation)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            RemoveTimer(namedInvocation);
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveTimer(string namedInvocation)
    {
        if (!timers.ContainsKey(namedInvocation)) return;
        timers[namedInvocation].Stop();
        timers.Remove(namedInvocation);
    } 


}
```

Then we invoke using

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DelayInvoke("InitSomething",()=> {
    DoSomething();
},TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check IsLoaded property for view, when view is in loaded form it returns false, when view is fully loaded, this property become true.

Thanks,
Rajnikant

Comment: It`s not working. The isLoaded gets true value before the view is rendered

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding to the [ContentRendered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  event? It will occur after the loaded event, yet I´m not sure whether or not this is a gurantee that the UI thread has finished painting the window then.

Comment: I use User Control and not a Window so the event ContentRendered isn`t exists.

Comment: Is your control dynamically added to the window? If not, bind to the event of the parent window

Answer (score 0):

You can Write a "Thread.Sleep(10000)" in the first line of "CommandExecute" method. Use the same loaded trigger.

if you don't want to use Thread.Sleep then you can go for "DispatcherTimer". Start a timer in your command execute method and shift all your code to timer tick event. 
set your timer interval to 2 seconds, so that user will sen the UI.

Comment: I thought about it but if it possible I prefer avoid from executing commands base on time assumptions

Comment: Even i don't like using timer in my application, but i don't think we have any events in WPF which will be fired after few seconds after loading. if you want to show UI for a while before executing command then you are forced to use timer.

Comment: Agree with Offir. As a general rule, never make time assumptions to solve race conditions.Triggering on Application.Idle as Louis Kauffman showed is best.

Answer (score 0):

I came with this solution for this one.
I wanted to use a boolean property set as true at start of work and to false at the end to allow to notify user of background work.

Basically, it uses

- a `DispatcherTimer` to launch a method after UI render according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026826/execute-command-after-view-is-loaded-wpf-mvvm)
- An async method wich will execute the `Action` passed as a parameter

**Call :**

```
this.LaunchThisWhenUiLoaded(() => { /*Stuff to do after Ui loaded here*/ });
```

**Method :**

```
private DispatcherTimer dispatchTimer;
private Action ActionToExecuteWhenUiLoaded;

/// <summary>
/// Handy method to launch an Action after full UI rendering
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toExec"></param>
protected void LaunchThisWhenUiLoaded(Action toExec)
{            
    ActionToExecuteWhenUiLoaded = toExec;
    // Call UiLoaded method when UI is loaded and rendered
    dispatchTimer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.Zero, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, UiLoaded, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
}

/// <summary>
/// Method called after UI rendered
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected async void UiLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsBusy = true;    

    if (ActionToExecuteWhenUiLoaded != null)
        await Task.Run(ActionToExecuteWhenUiLoaded);
    dispatchTimer.Stop();

    this.IsBusy = false;
}
```

Maybe not the clean but it works as expected.